# Watir-Webdriver: Puts statement not getting printed to hudson console in real time

Tags: ruby, hudson, jenkins, watir, watir-webdriver

I am running few tests using watir-webdriver[ruby], and in those tests I have added few puts statements which will print to the console. When running in terminal/command prompt, the messages are printed to the console immediately.

But when I run the same tests from Hudson, the print does not happen in real time. Instead, it  will wait till the job completes and at the end it will dump all the print at one shot.

This way, I am not able to check if my tests are running fine and their status in real time.

Are there any solutions for this?

Thanks
Sudhi

Update:

Adam, 
This did now work for me. My code snippet looks like this.

```
stdout.sync = true 
class TC_MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase 
$stdout.sync = true 
  def test_sample 
  $i=0 
  @@log.debug "Running the scenario = "+@@SCENARIO 
  puts "Running the scenario = "+@@SCENARIO 
     while $i<@@LOOPCOUNT 
       @@log.debug "Running the loop # "+$i.to_s 
       puts "Running the loop # "+$i.to_s 
       # Clean up the system 
       killOldProcesses() 
     end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: First off, add the '$' to the first stdout statement (at the top of the file) and delete the second $stdout statement as its unecessary.  If you tried running this manually you would probably see an error.  Please try it again and post results - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This statement prevents buffering of text so that it displays immediately - place it at the top of your script (for Cucumber I place it at the top of a file in my support directory):

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

Are you using any other frameworks/gems?  I had an issue with Jenkins not displaying puts statements in Cucumber scripts in real time.  The solution was to move those puts statements into my [Page Object pages](http://watir.com/2011/01/22/simple-cucumber-watir-page-object-pattern-framework/) rather than the steps files (Feature -> Steps -> Pages).

Using both of these conventions, I get real time Jenkins output as desired.

Comment: Sudhindra, can you please edit your original post to include that code?  That will make it more easily readable.

Comment: Adam, I have updated my original post with proper code. Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: if this 'did now work for' you, can you tick the checkmark to mark this answer correct?

Comment: Hi Adam,I added '$' to the first stdout and removed the second one. But its not working. The puts is not appearing the hudson console instantly.

Comment: Sudhindra - My only guess with the provided code would be that because you're running parallel threads that it is waiting for a thread to exit before printing to the console - Hudson *should* not treat this any differently.

Comment: I tried STDOUT.flush, $stdout.flush and STDOUT.puts, nothing is of any help. I am still facing this issue....